# remote files have 0 bytes when uploaded via sftp with phpseclib

Tags: php, cron, sftp, phpseclib

i have Server 2008 R2 with xampp (1.7.7) running.
i try to use sftp with phpseclib.
when i load the php page manually, all works fine.
when the page is loaded via cronjob, i get 0 Byte files on the remote Computer.

here is the php code:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('remote.server');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->put($filename.".DAT", $filename.".DAT", NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

and here the .bat for the cronjob:

```
@E:\WSERVER\xampp\php\php.exe -f E:\WSERVER\xampp\htdocs\sites\anq\file.php
```

what could be the Problem?
the local files are fine, either way...

regards j

Comment: could you show the code where $filename is initialized? are you using $_GET or $_POST?

Comment: Does the file.php have any more code than that, such as any Includes?

Comment: also, do you rely on relative paths in your code?

Comment: hi Mario, thanks for the quick reply, here ist the code:    $file = fopen("E:\\WSERVER\\xampp\\htdocs\\path\\".$filename.".DAT","w");
$content = $manyVariables."|".$withPipeSeperators."|";
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);

Comment: sorry, i'm having Problems making new lines here... which paths do you mean?

Comment: hi matthew, yes of course, it is over 300 lines Long, here are the includes: set_include_path(get_include_path() . '\\' . 'phpseclib' . '\\');
include('Net\SSH2.php');
include('Net\SFTP.php'); best regards

Comment: @jochen, what is the value of $filename? because of the usage, i think it is just that, for example "file", and you then use a relative path in $sftp->put. could you try doing `$path="E:\\WSERVER\\xampp\\htdocs\\path\\".$filename.".DAT"` and using this variable in both `fopen` and `$sftp->put` instead of $filename?

Comment: dear mario and neubert, i will be back at work wednesday and try with the absolute path. thanks! regards j

Comment: @Mario, that was it! :) absolute paths are working, thank you very much! regards j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to your Net_SFTP::put() call is as follows:

```
$filename.".DAT"
```

My guess is that that's a relative path and that the directory the cron job (or Windows Scheduler task) is being ran out of isn't the same as it is when you run it manually.

ie. the solution would be to make the second parameter be an absolute path to the file location.

Comment: thank you for the very appreciated help, i was a bit lost, not knowing enough about the put behaviour of the phpseclib. putting the absolute path in the second Parameter solved my Problem: '$sftp->put($filename.".DAT", "E:\\WSERVER\\xampp\\htdocs\\path\\".$filename.".DAT", NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);' regards j